# ffmpeg rotate video according to sensor data

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to scale videos down captured by the Android cellphones in order to reduce amount of data to be uploaded to the server. What I'm doing right now is:

`String.format("-i %s -vf \"scale='if(gt(a,1),-1,%d)':'if(gt(1,a),%d,-1)'\" -strict -2 %s", in, h, w, out);`

It scales down well. But users often hold their phoned in different orientation. When original video is played on a device it is rotated according to rotation saved in metadata. But after encoding video does not contain this information.

How can I perform scaling that rotates video according to this data or at least to store this data in output file ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a recent build of `ffmpeg`. It will automatically rotate according to the rotate metadata/sidedata. After rotation the rotate metadata is dropped.

Also, consider [stream copying](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio instead of re-encoding it.